# .Net Webcam Media Server for Html5

Tags: c#, webcam, signalr

I am trying to create an Html5 media server that can take in and stream out webcam video and need a bit more direction.
What ways can a webcam via Html5 be streamed to a server and how should the server stream it back out to the client?
Is there a way to do this via something like SignalR?
Are there any real-time compression server side .net dlls that can be used to take the incoming video and stream it to clients?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 `<video>` tag is protocol agnostic. This means that it does not care about the video format.

The issue that you have is knowing what browsers support a streaming format. Some browsers support RTP or ASF streams. At the moment there is no streaming format that all browsers support. HTML5 isn't your best option for streaming today.